# How do I partition my images for OpenStack?

Tags: server, openstack

I'm following the Ubuntu OpenStack Beginners Guide at:

http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/starter/content/Base_OS-d1e542.html

I have used Ubuntu for some years, but always just accepted the standard partition set-up. I'm now following the instructions which say use Ubuntu Server, and now I am not sure how to set-up the partitions in the format asked for:

> We will also be running nova-volume on this server and it is ideal to
>   have a dedicated partition for the use of nova-volume. So, ensure that
>   you choose manual partitioning scheme while installing Ubuntu Server
>   and create a dedicated partition with adequate amount of space for
>   this purpose. We have referred to this partition in the rest of the
>   chapter as /dev/sda6. You can substitute the correct device name of
>   this dedicated partition based on your local setup while following the
>   instructions. Also ensure that the partition type is set as Linux LVM
>   (8e) using fdisk either during install or immediately after
>   installation is over. If you also plan to use a dedicated partition as
>   Swift backend, create another partition for this purpose and follow
>   the instructions in "Swift Installation" section below.

Would anyone be able to advice?

Also, I am assuming I am OK to use VirtualBox Images.

Finally, on the network configuration instructions:

http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/starter/content/Network_Configuration-d1e591.html

Do I actually use the settings below, I do I have to adjust for my settings?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.10.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.10.10.255
gateway 10.10.10.1
dns-nameservers 10.10.8.3

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.3.0
broadcast 192.168.3.255
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need. The LV 'nova-volumes' is used for volumes that can be attached to virtual machines. Like the Amazon EBS, if you plan to use only virtual machines without the need of adding/removing volumes you can keep it small (about 50-100 gb) else you need to increase the size.

Other storage paths are `/var/lib/nova/instances` for instances disk and `/var/lib/glance/images` for server images and snapshots.

About the network configuration it seems correct, depends if you have multiple machines to work with or all in one.